# Crontab doesn't work after reboot by cable plugging out

Tags: python, cron

I have a crontab task for python script (IOT hub by microsoft) launch. 
It launches properly after "sudo reboot" and by manual script launch, but doesn't launch properly after reboot by cable plugging out and inserting back.
But process always shows up in htop.

I'm running crontab editor by

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Here's my crontab.

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /usr/bin/python /home/pi/iot-hub-python-raspberrypi-client-app/app.py >> /home/pi/myjob.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: What is "shutdown by cable"? And what does the log say?

Comment: @MatsK "shutdown by cable" - pull powercable out and insert it again.
Log is empy. If i will restart rpi by "sudo reboot" - it shows script stdout

Comment: Pulling the powercable is a big "No No", a OS needs to take down processes, filesystem in an orderly manner. Pulling the powercable is asking for trouble!

Comment: I know it, but I'm making a project for a client who would not reboot it by sudo reboot and can't make a sudo reboot after power outage, for example. @MatsK

Comment: Hockup a button to a GPIO that trigger a shutdown! And edit sudoers so the user can make a rebot without sudo.

Comment: how do you expect to run a script when the RPi is dead?

Comment: Pulling the power cable from the RPi will sooner or later result in corrupted data and a broken operating system. If you or your client proceed with this method, the not working cronjob will be the least evil. I agree with MatsK: attach a physical button.